# Dhtmlx scheduler Lightbox

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

How can I aligning two fields in a single row in scheduler config light-box sections, And not below one another.

```
Name [(FirstName)] [(Lastname)] [(Middlename)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going out on limb here. Shouldn't you be able to use the following to combine them in a single string. Either beforehand or while returning the value.

```
return "Name: " + Firstname + ' '  + Lastname + ' ' + Middlename;
```